# MS SQL Select Where ntext-Column contains specific hex String

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem in a select on mssql

in my table there is a column with datatype ntext and i'm searching for an specific character.
when i read the value and convert it to hex ill get something like that

```
SELECT convert(varbinary(max),convert(nvarchar(max),COLUMN_Value))  FROM db.TABLE WHERE PK = 1234

0x3C005000200063006C006100730073003D004D0073006F004E006F0072006D0061006C0020007300740...
```

In the hex value there is for example 3C00, when I now rewrite my select and search for this value no row is matching :/

```
SELECT * FROM db.TABLE WHERE convert(varbinary(max),convert(nvarchar(max),COLUMN_Value)) LIKE '%3C00%'
```

Does anybody know whats the problem here?

Comment: I assume that you want to search for a string that contains the encoded bytes for `3C` and then `00`. What if the string is just `03C004` ? Should that match? (note that this contains the encoded bytes for `03`, `C0` and then `04`).

Comment: no, it should only match when the converted column value contains this string.  the background is, i search for "damaged" rows which contain a character (  ) which cannot be displayed
in hex it is C0DB. But when I convert the column in where clause matching is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i've done it with following query

```
SELECT * FROM db.TABLE WHERE CONVERT(varchar(max),convert(varbinary(max),convert(nvarchar(max),COLUMN_Value)),2) LIKE '%3C00%';
```

i used the hex value from my first query (3C00) and found every row containing it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM db.TABLE WHERE convert(nvarchar(max),COLUMN_Value) LIKE '%3C00%'
```

Comment: If you get the column in varchar or nvarchar, it should work. What are you getting?

Comment: As you see in my question, when I do the select (convert(varbinary(max),convert(nvarchar(max),COLUMN_Value))) i get lots of rows which starts with 0x3C00. But if i perform the query no row match

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bd822/3/0 . but thats really strange, when i run the query on microsoft sql management studio, i'll get 0x3C005000200063006C0061007300730020003D0020002200740065007300740022003E00

Comment: What is the datatype you are using?